# In R Shiny, use stats::setNames to assign names to vector elements and then retrieve the name attributes in the server side

Tags: r, shiny, names

I have a shiny app that displays data from a database, in which variables are assigned codes (e.g., "TMAX" for maximum temperature, "GDD" for growing degree days, etc). The user will pick a variable that they want to display from a selectInput, and I assigned names to the elements of the choices vector using `stats::setNames()`. In the full version of the app, figures are created displaying data for the selected variable, and I want to be able to use the name of the element as the y-label for the plot (for example, if the variable is TMAX, then I want the y axis to display "Max Temperature"). The names that I've assigned appear in the selectInput dropdown, but the name attribute appears to be lost when the user actually selects an option; when I call `names()` on the selected input, it returns `NULL`.

This mini app shows the issue. (I'm just printing and rendering the name of the variable rather than creating a figure with the name as the label.)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    'select', 'Select',
    choices = stats::setNames(
      object = c('var1', 'var2', 'var3'),
      nm = c('Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3')
    )
  ),
  
  textOutput('var'),
  textOutput('varname')
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print(names(input$select))
    
    output$var <- renderText(paste('Variable:', input$select))
    output$varname <- renderText(paste('Variable name:', names(input$select)))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Comment: AFIK, although the select allows you to use names on the UI, they aren't passed to the reactive input in anyway. You'd need to look up the names again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SmokeyShakers, I made the following changes (between the hashes):

```
library(shiny)
########
vars <- stats::setNames(
  object = c('var1', 'var2', 'var3'),
  nm = c('Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3')
)
########

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    'select', 'Select',
    choices = vars
  ),
  
  textOutput('var'),
  textOutput('varname')
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    # print(names(input$select))
    
    output$var <- renderText(paste('Variable:', input$select))
    output$varname <- renderText(paste('Variable name:', 
                                       ########
                                       names(vars)[which(vars == input$select)]
                                       ########
                                      ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```